# Issue doing an npm install on windows using git bash for angular.io quick start

Tags: angularjs, npm, git-bash, angular

Trying to do an npm install on windows for angular.io quick start: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

Problem is once I've cloned I get this git bash error:

**shasum check failed for...**

This occurs when I do "**npm install**" on a **windows** with **git bash**.

Does anyone know any other **angular4** seed apps I could use or a fix for the angular.io quickstart?

**Screen shot of bug:**

[image]

Comment: I can understand the frustration caused due to `npm install`.

Comment: @DevendraLattu Thanks. I just want to get the angular 4 quickstart app running so I can test the view engine for an angular 4 app. In the past I've used Angular 2 and the performance was dreadful, especially on iPhone and Android devices for first time loading (I'm hoping with angular 4 that the initial loading of a app with several routes is much faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please run below command and try again? If you get same error then please post error log.

> npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: That worked. But next I needed to find the .npmrc file under users. I then had to set: always-auth=false